The connection was reset on nginx second server
I am trying to run: localhost:9000 with PHP 8.3, while going into localhost:5000 works perfectly fine. Trying localhost:9000 leads to

The connection was reset

message.
Restarting nginx -s reload does not show any messages.
Configuration as follows:
# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
server {
    listen       9000;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        index  index.php;
    }
    
    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           www;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}

I run:

C:\php8.3\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 (From within the nginx root folder)
C:\nginx\nginx

Go to: localhost:5000, and a html page of Nginx appears.

Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
and working. Further configuration is required.

Inside the C:\nginx folder, I created a folder called: www and inside it, I have a file called: index.php which contains: <?php phpinfo(); ?>.

According to your config you have fastcgi listening on port 9000. You can't have two things listening to the same port. Use a different port for nginx listen directive.
You have:
listen       9000;

[...]
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

According to your config nginx should listen on  port 9000, and you also tell nginx that fastcgi is listening on port 9000. You can't have two processes using the same port.

The first server listens on localhost:5000 and it's working. The second listens on port 9000 and this does not work. The fastcgi has to run on that same port, what am I missing. (At least every tutorial says so).

You have listen 9000 in your config, which means you instruct nginx to listen to port 9000.

Vidarlo, yes, I have, because, I want to: localhost:9000, is this wrong?

Yes - and I would in general suggest either following tutorials or understanding them when you deviate.
